# window geometry from command line

Tags: xorg, plasma

I am using kubuntu 20.04.

The command line

```
 xterm  -geometry 3840x2160+0+4320
```

works as expected but

```
 firefox  -geometry 3840x2160+0+4320
```

it does not (it works only pure X applications). What is the correct command line?

Comment: Is `firefox --help` any useful?

Comment: Non really. In any case I am looking for a solution that applies to all applications (`firefox` is just an example).